# how to publish a flow-typed library with its own types

Tags: flowtype, flow-typed

I've written a `index.js` module in flow which I transpiled with Babel, placed within a `/dist` directory and defined as the main file in the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-lib",
  "version": "0.9.0",
  "description": "...",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
...
}
```

the `dist` directory only contains the transpiled file.

when I use it on another project, by importing via npm or yarn (`yarn add <my-local-path-to-the-module>`), I can import into my project's modules but I lose the original flow definitions (of course, babel stripped them). How could I associate the flow definitions along with the transpiled file so as to have the module as well as its Flow types ready to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating your dist files, you need to create associating declaration files from your source code. https://flow.org/en/docs/declarations/

So in the end your dist dir would have a file structure like

```
- dist
    - index.js
    - index.flow.js
    - something.js
    - something.flow.js
    - dir1
        file1.js
        file1.flow.js
```

You can use either https://github.com/Macil/flow-copy-source or https://github.com/lessmess-dev/gen-flow-files

Comment: it didn't work actually :(
The only way I've found to make it work is ysubg `gen-flow-files` and force to read the definition into my `.flowconfig` like this `[libs]
node_modules/<MY-LIB>/dist/index.js.flow`